# How I get the Android MediaPlayer running my http url? With other urls it works just fine

Tags: java, node.js, express, audio, android-mediaplayer

So I want to build an app which streams music from my backend server. For this I created a Node JS Express API with MongoDB. Then I have an url like this: `http://192.168.178.26:3000/stream?id=5dd5065f3b9a2a22149fdb09&format=mp3`

When I type in this url in my Browser (Opera) then it will stream the music as expected. Also with Postman it works.

Then I wrote an app for Android with Android Studio, which streams music from given url. This works fine when I tried this url: `https://www.ssaurel.com/tmp/mymusic.mp3`, but not with mine. When I tried this with my url the MediaPlayer failed while preparing. The Error is following: `Prepare failed.: status=0x1`. I searched for this error and I found it means `unknown Error`.

The code of my Backend:

```js
const express = require('express');
const dbHandler = require('./src/dbHandler/dbHandler.js');
const fs = require('fs');
const app = express();

app.get('/stream', (req, res) => {
    console.log(`Got stream request from ${req.ip}...`);
    dbHandler.getFilePath(req.query.id, req.query.format).then((path) => {
        let stat = fs.statSync(path);
        res.set({
            'Content-Type': 'audio/mpeg',
            'Content-Length': stat.size,
            'Accept-Ranges': 'bytes',
            'Cache-Control': 'max-age=3600'
        });
        fs.createReadStream(path).pipe(res);
    }).catch(err => {
        res.status(400).send(err)
    })
})

app.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log(`Server is listening at 3000...`);
    dbHandler.init();
})
```

As you can see, when the server gets a stream request its printing it out. The `dbHandler.getFilePath()`-Method just returns the full path of the mp3 location like this: `D:/Music/song.mp3`. When I try this with postman, the server gets a request and prints it. Then Postman gets the stream back and I can start streaming the music.

When I tried this with my Browser on my Smartphone it worked either. So I can stream the music through the browser of my smartphone but not with my App.

It is important to notice, that when I try to prepare the MediaPlayer, the server dont get a request. So it is not logging to console, that a request was commited.

This is the Code of my App:

```java
package sharemusic.truerushhunt3r.de.sharemusic.frontend;

import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.IOException;

import sharemusic.truerushhunt3r.de.sharemusic.R;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    //private GetHandler getHandler;
    private boolean isPlaying = false;
    private boolean initialStage = true;
    private MediaPlayer player;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //getHandler = new GetHandler();
        player = new MediaPlayer();
        player.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);

        ImageButton playButton = findViewById(R.id.playButton);
        playButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (!isPlaying) {
                    Log.d("ShareMusic/Button", "Play pressed");
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Play", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    if (initialStage) {
                        //new Player().execute("https://www.ssaurel.com/tmp/mymusic.mp3");
                        new Player().execute("http://192.168.178.26:3000/stream?id=5dd5065f3b9a2a22149fdb09&format=mp3");                    
                    } else {
                        if (!player.isPlaying()) {
                            player.start();
                        }
                    }
                    isPlaying = true;
                } else {
                    Log.d("ShareMusic/Button", "Pause pressed");
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Pause", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    if (player.isPlaying()) {
                        player.pause();
                    }

                    isPlaying = false;
                }
            }
        });  
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();

        if (player != null) {
            player.reset();
            player.release();
            player = null;
        }
    }

    class Player extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean> {
        @Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(String... strings) {
            Boolean prepared = false;

            try {
                player.setDataSource(getApplicationContext(), Uri.parse(strings[0]));
                player.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                        initialStage = true;
                        isPlaying = false;
                        mp.stop();
                        mp.reset();
                    }
                });

                player.prepare();
                prepared = true;
            } catch(Exception e) {
                Log.e("ShareMusic", e.getMessage());
            }
            return prepared;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Boolean aBoolean) {
            super.onPostExecute(aBoolean);
            if (aBoolean) {
                player.start();
                initialStage = false;
                isPlaying = false;
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Failed to prepare", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                initialStage = true;
                isPlaying = false;
            }
        }

    }
}
```

[The Response Headers of my url: http://192.168.178.26:3000/stream?id=5dd5065f3b9a2a22149fdb09&format=mp3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9V99G.png)

[The Response Headers of the working url: https://www.ssaurel.com/tmp/mymusic.mp3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XAK3Y.png)

I dont think it has something to do with the http and https protocoll. But I dont really dont know what to do now. My Music file is supported by android (mp3) btw. Is my backend wrong or is it the app? And how can I fix the problem?

When something isn't clear, pls ask.

Android API Level: 19 and higher

Device: Huawei P20 Lite

OS: 9.1.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok guys, I got it! Check out this [website](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-network-security-config/index.html#3)! Basically instead of `cleartextTrafficPermitted="false"` you have to write `cleartextTrafficPermitted="true"` to make the magic happen.

So my conclusion is, that the mediaplayer didnt like the http connection, but liked the https. But I dont understand why it was not telling me this...